# Password does not work on custom install of CartoDB

Tags: carto

I got an installation of CartoDB working from a recent git pull; however, I cannot login.  I am using the domain:

development.localhost.lan

and username 'development'

The password is the one that I gave to create_dev_user.  I checked that there is an entry in the database for this user but whatever I do I cannot get it to login.

Any suggestions for what to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

When you run the full CartoDB stack with

```
 bundle exec foreman start -p 3000
```

You can view the logs in realtime. This should give you an error message that might make troubleshooting easier